# Setup SSH keys created by PuTTY in GitLab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, putty

I have generated a public and a private key using PuTTYgen and added the public key to my GitLab account, but when I try to clone the repository, it still wants a password.

I have read the following instructions from [this site](https://gist.github.com/njxqlus/3066306a1b37b7a05b1e801b2beea01c)

1. Install Putty and related utilities
2. Set system environment variable in Windows(Control Panel\System and Security\System --> and clicking on "Advanced system settings" in the left pane. Then click on "Environment Variables") GIT_SSH=%path_to_plink.exe% (Note plink.exe goes into wherever you installed Putty)
3. Generate a ssh key using puttygen.exe (ssh2-rsa, 4096, comment=GitLab, and set a passphrase)
4. Add key to pageant.exe and the public key to your GitLab profile
5. Ensure you start a new command shell so that git recognizes the GIT_SSH value
6. Try these two commands to check connection first. This should give you a popup window that authenticates connection
7. set Git putty git@gitlab.com:%user%/%repo.git%

Usage:

1. Start pagent.exe from Putty folder
2. Add key to pageant.exe

I still don't understand step 5 and in step 6 I see no shell commands to do the test.

Can anyone help?

Update:

The issue was that I didn't restart my cmd. But now I get this message:
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's ssh-ed25519 key fingerprint is:
ssh-ed25519 255 d7:0d:ca:f2:c1:01:46:80:68:4c:5d:e6:d4:52:f9:16
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n)

And it doesn't let me type anything there.

Comment: I think the problem was that I got my credentials in Credential Manager wrong. I changed them and it works now.

Comment: OK, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ensure you start a new command shell so that git recognizes the GIT_SSH value

Type `git bash`, then "`set|grep GIT_SSH`"

If the result is empty, the CMD session in which you opened your session did not inherit your Windows User environment variable. Open a new CMD.

But I would not recommend using Putty. Git for Windows comes with openssh, and that should be enough, in a git bash session

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa 
<enter a passphrase>
```

See more at GitHub (that will apply for GitLab as well) "[Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)"

The [OP Petar Yakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7094506/petar-yakov) reports having to register the password of their GitLab account in the Credential Manager.
Then the SSH access works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried the keygen command and it works fine, but I am using PuTTY to connect to a ssh server and I thought it would be cool if I use 1 public key for the server and for gitlab.

Comment: I updated the question with a new strange problem. Do you know something about it?

Comment: @PetarYakov you should be able to type 'y'. Try an ssh <user>@<server> from command line, just to trigger the same message and type y. Then retry your putty command: if the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` has been updated, it should not ask the question again.

Comment: This message appears when I try to clone a repository and now when I try to connect to the ssh server. What should I type for <user>@<server> in this case?

Comment: @PetarYakov If your remote repo is at gitlab.com, that would be `ssh git@gitlab.com`, again just to trigger the question. However, putty store those signatures differently than ssh: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter2.html#gs-hostkey. Check again if you can answer 'y' at any point when trying to connect to the server with putty.

Comment: Guess I will use 2 public keys :D . Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: The thing is that I am using a gitlab account from my uni and when I type the ssh command it wants some password and I don't know what it is. I tried the login pw, but it didn't work. And I didn't manage to type the 'y'. It just freezes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222592/discussion-between-vonc-and-petar-yakov).